# How to condense data irregularly distributed over several rows in an Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, microsoft-excel-365, concatenation, join

**Actual Table**: Data irregularly distributed over several rows and thus partially empty lines

| Date | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Date_1 | Text_1A |
|  | Text_1B |
| Date_3 | Text_3A |
|  | Text_3B |
|  | Text_3C |
| Date_6 | Text_6A |
|  | Text_6B |
| Date_8 | Text_8A |
|  | Text_8B |
|  | Text_8C |
| Date_11 | Text_11A |
|  | Text_11B |
| Date_13 | Text_13A |
|  | Text_13B |
|  | Text_13C |

**Desired Table**

| Date | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Date_1 | Text_1A Text_1B |
| Date_2 | Text_2A Text_2B Text_2C |
| Date_3 | Text_3A Text_3B |
| Date_4 | Text_4A Text_4B Text_4C |
| Date_5 | Text_5A Text_5B |
| Date_6 | Text_6A Text_6B Text_6C |

- If there were regular intervals, I would use the CONCATENATE
  function. Unfortunately, it is irregular.
- There are about 8'000 rows.
- I have Microsoft 365 with Excel. Additionally, I have access LibreOffice or the Command Line on Ubuntu.
- If this question was already asked, could you kindly link it or
  indicate the relevant search tags, as I didn't find anything.

Additional information in response to Scott Craner:
Data preferably to be filled into the first row of the set.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Look into TEXTJOIN and FILTER, but they will require that the data is complete.  It gets real difficult with the blanks and assuming the data should be the last filled in cell.

Comment: 1) Start with a helper column with appropriate formula(s) to fill in the empty dates in your original data table, then 2) in the results table use `UNIQUE()` to get the dates and then 3) use @ScottCraner suggestion

Comment: Or you can spend time to learn how to do with with power query or VBA...

Answer (score 2):

Using LET, SCAN, BYROW, and LAMBDA:

```
=LET(
    d,A2:A16,
    t,B2:B16,
    f,SCAN(a,A2:A16,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b<>"",b,a))),
    u,UNIQUE(f),
    CHOOSE({1,2},u,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTER(t,f=a,""))))))
```

`f` is a full array of the normalized dates, it basically fills any empty cell with the value from above.

Then we get a unique list and go row by row and join the text from the text column where they are for the unique date.

A couple of Caveats:

1. There is no garauntee that this will be performant on 8,000 rows.  It could get bogged down doing so many calculations.
2. There is a limit to the number of characters a cell can hold it is 32,767.  If any of the TEXTJOIN outputs are more than that it will cause an error.
   [image]

Comment: Nice example, now to go and read up on these new (to me) formulas.

Comment: I am getting the following error: The first argument of LET must be a valid name.

Comment: Take out the first line break. @nemu